# Remove delay while pressing the second key LWJGL Java

Tags: java, input, lwjgl

I am running into a problem that I cannot find any solution for the moment even by searching on the internet.

I am currently working on a 2D game and I want my player to go on every direction and diagonally. For that reason I need to get two inputs from the keyboard, thing that I could code but now my problem is, when I press the second key, I have a slight delay where my player do not move. This is very annoying because the movement is not smooth at all when I am changing my direction.
Here my class where I manage all the inputs.
Thanks in advance for your help.

```java
public class Input
{
    private static final Input INSTANCE = new Input();
    
    public final static float PI = (float) 3.141592;
    public final static float P2 = (float) (PI/2);
    
    private double x = Jeu.Isaac.getDeplacement().getHit().getEntity().getX();
    private double y = Jeu.Isaac.getDeplacement().getHit().getEntity().getY();
    private double a = Jeu.Isaac.getDeplacement().getA();
    
    private final int[] listeInput = {GLFW.GLFW_KEY_A, GLFW.GLFW_KEY_D, GLFW.GLFW_KEY_W, GLFW.GLFW_KEY_S,
            GLFW.GLFW_KEY_UP, GLFW.GLFW_KEY_DOWN, GLFW.GLFW_KEY_RIGHT, GLFW.GLFW_KEY_LEFT};
    
    private double speed = 5.85;

    public void drawBalle() 
    {
        Jeu.Isaac.getMunitions().drawBalle();
    }
    
    public DeplacerPersonnage getPlayerMove() {
        return Jeu.Isaac.getDeplacement();
    }
    
    private GLFWKeyCallback keyboard;
    
    private HashMap<Integer, Boolean> mappageTouches;
    
    private Input()
    {
        mappageTouches = new HashMap<Integer, Boolean>();
        
        for(int key:listeInput)
        {
            mappageTouches.put(key, false);
        }

        keyboard = new GLFWKeyCallback()
        {

            @Override
            public void invoke(long window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods) 
            {
                if(action == GLFW.GLFW_RELEASE)
                {
                    mappageTouches.replace(key, false);
                }
                else if(action == GLFW.GLFW_PRESS)
                {
                    System.out.println("Pressed");
                    mappageTouches.replace(key, true);
                    getAWSDkeys();
                    getShotsKeys();
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("hold");
                    getAWSDkeys();
                    getShotsKeys();
                }
            }
            
        };
    }
    
    
    public void getAWSDkeys()
    {
        for(Integer key:listeInput)
        {
            if(mappageTouches.get(key))
            {
                switch(key)
                {
                    case GLFW.GLFW_KEY_A:
                        a = PI;
                        if(!Jeu.Isaac.getDeplacement().getHit().isQCollision()) x -= speed;
                        Jeu.Isaac.getDeplacement().update(x, y, a);
                        Jeu.Isaac.getDeplacement().drawPlayer();
                        break;
                    case GLFW.GLFW_KEY_D:
                        a = 0;
                        if(!Jeu.Isaac.getDeplacement().getHit().isDCollision()) x += speed;
                        Jeu.Isaac.getDeplacement().update(x, y, a);
                        Jeu.Isaac.getDeplacement().drawPlayer();
                        break;
                    case GLFW.GLFW_KEY_W:
                        a = PI/2;
                        if(!Jeu.Isaac.getDeplacement().getHit().isZCollision()) y += speed;
                        Jeu.Isaac.getDeplacement().update(x, y, a);
                        Jeu.Isaac.getDeplacement().drawPlayer();
                        break;
                    case GLFW.GLFW_KEY_S:
                        a = 3*(PI/2);
                        if(!Jeu.Isaac.getDeplacement().getHit().isSCollision()) y -= speed;
                        Jeu.Isaac.getDeplacement().update(x, y, a);
                        Jeu.Isaac.getDeplacement().drawPlayer();
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

    }
    
    public void getShotsKeys()
    {
        for(Integer key:listeInput)
        {
            if(mappageTouches.get(key))
            {
                switch(key)
                {
                    case GLFW.GLFW_KEY_UP:
                        Jeu.Isaac.getMunitions().addBalle(new Balle(1, 1, Jeu.Isaac.getDeplacement().getHit().getEntity().getX(), Jeu.Isaac.getDeplacement().getHit().getEntity().getY(), 3));
                        break;
                    case GLFW.GLFW_KEY_DOWN:
                        Jeu.Isaac.getMunitions().addBalle(new Balle(1, 1, Jeu.Isaac.getDeplacement().getHit().getEntity().getX(), Jeu.Isaac.getDeplacement().getHit().getEntity().getY(), 4));
                        break;
                    case GLFW.GLFW_KEY_RIGHT:
                        Jeu.Isaac.getMunitions().addBalle(new Balle(1, 1, Jeu.Isaac.getDeplacement().getHit().getEntity().getX(), Jeu.Isaac.getDeplacement().getHit().getEntity().getY(), 2));
                        break;
                    case GLFW.GLFW_KEY_LEFT:
                        Jeu.Isaac.getMunitions().addBalle(new Balle(1, 1, Jeu.Isaac.getDeplacement().getHit().getEntity().getX(), Jeu.Isaac.getDeplacement().getHit().getEntity().getY(), 1));
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    public static Input getInstance()
    {
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    public void init(long window)
    {
        glfwSetKeyCallback(window, keyboard);
    }
    
}
```

Comment: When dealing with things like direct player input , its not recommended to use callbacks. You should use Input Polling. For that , you can use the `glfwGetKey(long window, int key);` function directly in your game , or in a simple class. https://www.glfw.org/docs/3.3/group__input.html#gadd341da06bc8d418b4dc3a3518af9ad2

Comment: I've made your recommended changes but nothing change, I think it's because I using it in the Invoke of key GLFWKeyCallback() but I don't understand where do I have to put it else ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your input handling logic, like incrementing your `x` variable via `x += speed;` (in `getAWSDkeys()`) is only performed when the OS sends window event messages for your keyboard. That only happens for KEY_DOWN, KEY_UP and KEY_REPEAT events. And, yes, there is a delay between a KEY_DOWN and a KEY_REPEAT event when you press and hold the same key.

In order to fix that, you just have to move your game logic (like the aforementioned increment/decrement of the `x` or `y` variable) *outside* of the key event handler.

Normally, you have a game loop for that, which also calls `glfwPollEvents()` (or `glfwWaitEvents()` if you decoupled your input/window event handling from rendering).

So, your keyboard event handler function should only set some boolean flag for every possible key indicating that this key is now down/pressed or up/released.
And in your game/input loop, you just query the state of your boolean flags and act accordingly by doing the `x`/`y` increment/decrement there.

Instead of storing your own boolean flags for all keys whether they are down/up, you can also use the `glfwGetKey()` function. Note, though, that this function *does not* query the current key state, but returns cached key state (cached intside of GLFW) which GLFW sets/remembers internally when you call `glfwPollEvents()`/`glfwWaitEvents()`.
See: https://www.glfw.org/docs/3.3/input_guide.html#input_key

> This function only returns cached key event state. It does not poll the system for the current physical state of the key.

In short: The problem is that your game logic is *inside* of the window event message callback (which is called by `glfwPollEvents`/`glfwWaitEvents` when there are keyboard events sent by the OS to your process/game). You must decouple the handling of input events from the actual game logic.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my late rely, I was quite busy.

I eventually solve my problem which was the callback logic.
I delete all, and I directly work with glfwGetKey() and it worked.

Here the code I made if it can help some people.

````java
public class Input
{
    private static final Input INSTANCE = new Input();
    
    public final static float PI = (float) 3.141592;
    public final static float P2 = (float) (PI/2);
    
    private double x = Jeu.Isaac.getPosition().getY();
    private double y = Jeu.Isaac.getPosition().getX();
    private double a = Jeu.Isaac.getA();
    
    private final int[] listeInput = {GLFW.GLFW_KEY_A, GLFW.GLFW_KEY_D, GLFW.GLFW_KEY_W, GLFW.GLFW_KEY_S, GLFW.GLFW_KEY_I, GLFW.GLFW_KEY_L, GLFW.GLFW_KEY_K, GLFW.GLFW_KEY_P,GLFW.GLFW_KEY_O,
            GLFW.GLFW_KEY_SPACE, GLFW.GLFW_KEY_UP, GLFW.GLFW_KEY_DOWN, GLFW.GLFW_KEY_RIGHT, GLFW.GLFW_KEY_LEFT};
    
    private double speed = 5.85;

    public void drawBalle() 
    {
        Jeu.Isaac.getMunitions().drawBalle();
    }

    public Personnage getPlayerMove() {
        return Jeu.Isaac;
    }
    
    private GLFWKeyCallback keyboard;
    
    //private HashMap<Integer, Boolean> mappageTouches;
    
    private Input()
    {
        /*mappageTouches = new HashMap<Integer, Boolean>();
        
        for(int key:listeInput)
        {
            mappageTouches.put(key, false);
        }*/

        /*keyboard = new GLFWKeyCallback()
        {
            @Override
            public void invoke(long window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods) 
            {
                if(glfwGetKey(window, key) == GLFW_PRESS)
                {
                    System.out.println("Pressed");
                    getAWSDkeys(window);
                    getShotsKeys(window);
                }
                if(glfwGetKey(window, key) == GLFW_RELEASE)
                {
                    glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_STICKY_KEYS, GLFW_FALSE);
                    System.out.println("Released");
                }
            }
            
        };*/
    }
    
    public void deplacement()
    {
        for(Integer key:listeInput)
        {
            checkDeplacement(Fenetre.getInstance().getWindow(), key);
        }
        Jeu.Isaac.updateGameObject();
    }
    
    public void tire()
    {
        for(Integer key:listeInput)
        {
            checkTire(Fenetre.getInstance().getWindow(), key);
        }
    }
    
    /**
     * Méthode qui vérifie si une touche a été pressée.
     * Si oui renvoie vers la méthode getAWSDkeys(window).
     * Si non, définie l'entrée rémanente à faux.
     * @param window
     * La fenêtre active.
     * @param key
     * La touche détectée à vérifier.
     */
    public void checkDeplacement(long window, int key)
    {
        if(glfwGetKey(window, key) == GLFW_PRESS)
        {
    //      System.out.println("Pressed");
            getAWSDkeys(window);
        }
        if(glfwGetKey(window, key) == GLFW_RELEASE)
        {
            glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_STICKY_KEYS, GLFW_FALSE);
    //      System.out.println("Released");
        }
    }
    
    public void checkTire(long window, int key)
    {
        if(glfwGetKey(window, key) == GLFW_PRESS)
        {
    //      System.out.println("Pressed");
            getShotsKeys(window);
        }
        if(glfwGetKey(window, key) == GLFW_RELEASE)
        {
            glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_STICKY_KEYS, GLFW_FALSE);
    //      System.out.println("Released");
        }
    }
    
    public void moveUp()
    {
        if(!Jeu.Isaac.getHitbox().isZCollision()) {
            Jeu.Isaac.goUpNext();
        }
        Jeu.Isaac.setA(PI/2);
        Jeu.Isaac.drawPlayer();
    }
    
    public void moveDown()
    {
        if(!Jeu.Isaac.getHitbox().isSCollision()) {
            Jeu.Isaac.goDownNext();
        }
        Jeu.Isaac.setA(3*PI/2);
        Jeu.Isaac.drawPlayer();
    }
    
    public void moveRight()
    {
        a = 0;
        if(!Jeu.Isaac.getHitbox().isDCollision()) {
            Jeu.Isaac.goRightNext();
        }
        Jeu.Isaac.setA(0);
        Jeu.Isaac.drawPlayer();
    }
    
    public void moveLeft()
    {
        a = PI;
        if(!Jeu.Isaac.getHitbox().isQCollision()) {
            Jeu.Isaac.goLeftNext();
        }
        Jeu.Isaac.setA(PI);
        Jeu.Isaac.drawPlayer();
    }
    
    public void poseBomb() {
        ObjetsInventaire bomb = new ObjetsInventaire(-1, 100, 100, Jeu.gameWorld.getPlayer().getPosition(), "");
    }
    
    public void shootUp()
    {
        Jeu.Isaac.getMunitions().addBalle(new Balle(25, 25, Jeu.Isaac.getPosition().getX(), Jeu.Isaac.getPosition().getY(), new Vector2(0, 1), "", 10));
        Jeu.gameWorld.getPlayer().setFace(1);
    }
    
    public void shootDown()
    {
        Jeu.Isaac.getMunitions().addBalle(new Balle(25, 25, Jeu.Isaac.getPosition().getX(), Jeu.Isaac.getPosition().getY(), new Vector2(0, -1), "", 10));
        Jeu.gameWorld.getPlayer().setFace(2);
    }
    
    public void shootRight()
    {
        Jeu.Isaac.getMunitions().addBalle(new Balle(25, 25, Jeu.Isaac.getPosition().getX(), Jeu.Isaac.getPosition().getY(), new Vector2(1, 0), "", 10));
        Jeu.gameWorld.getPlayer().setFace(3);
    }
    
    public void shootLeft()
    {
        Jeu.Isaac.getMunitions().addBalle(new Balle(25, 25, Jeu.Isaac.getPosition().getX(), Jeu.Isaac.getPosition().getY(), new Vector2(-1, 0), "", 10));
        Jeu.gameWorld.getPlayer().setFace(4);
    }
    
    public void getAWSDkeys(long window)
    {
        if(glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_W) == GLFW.GLFW_PRESS)
        {
            moveUp();
            glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_STICKY_KEYS, GLFW_TRUE);
        }
        if(glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_S) == GLFW.GLFW_PRESS)
        {
            moveDown();
            glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_STICKY_KEYS, GLFW_TRUE);
        }
        if(glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_D) == GLFW.GLFW_PRESS)
        {
            moveRight();
            glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_STICKY_KEYS, GLFW_TRUE);
        }
        if(glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_A) == GLFW.GLFW_PRESS)
        {
            moveLeft();
            glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_STICKY_KEYS, GLFW_TRUE);
        }
        if(glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_L) == GLFW.GLFW_PRESS)
        {
            Jeu.gameWorld.getPlayer().setSpeed(20);
            glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_STICKY_KEYS, GLFW_TRUE);
        }
        if(glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_I) == GLFW.GLFW_PRESS)
        {
            Jeu.gameWorld.getPlayer().setInvincible(true);
            glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_STICKY_KEYS, GLFW_TRUE);
        }
        if(glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_K) == GLFW.GLFW_PRESS)
        {
            Jeu.gameWorld.getMapEnCours().setListeEnnemi(new listeEnnemi());
            glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_STICKY_KEYS, GLFW_TRUE);
        }
        if(glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_P) == GLFW.GLFW_PRESS)
        {
            Jeu.gameWorld.getPlayer().setDegat(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
            glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_STICKY_KEYS, GLFW_TRUE);
        }
        if(glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_O) == GLFW.GLFW_PRESS)
        {
            Jeu.gameWorld.getPlayer().setCoin(Jeu.gameWorld.getPlayer().getCoin() + 10); //TODO pas fini
            glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_STICKY_KEYS, GLFW_TRUE);
        }
        if(glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_SPACE) == GLFW.GLFW_PRESS)
        {
            poseBomb();
            glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_STICKY_KEYS, GLFW_TRUE);
        }
    }
    
    public void getShotsKeys(long window)
    {
        if(glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_UP) == GLFW.GLFW_PRESS)
        {
            shootUp();
            glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_STICKY_KEYS, GLFW_TRUE);
        }
        if(glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_DOWN) == GLFW.GLFW_PRESS)
        {
            shootDown();
            glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_STICKY_KEYS, GLFW_TRUE);
        }
        if(glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_RIGHT) == GLFW.GLFW_PRESS)
        {
            shootRight();
            glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_STICKY_KEYS, GLFW_TRUE);
        }
        if(glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_LEFT) == GLFW.GLFW_PRESS)
        {
            shootLeft();
            glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_STICKY_KEYS, GLFW_TRUE);
        }
    }
    
    public void init(long window)
    {
        
    }

    public static Input getInstance() {
        return INSTANCE;
    }
}```
````